# tomcat congiguration : redirect url to another instance

Tags: apache, tomcat, configuration, instance, redirect

I have 2 tomcat instances behind an apache server :

- tomcat 7 on port 8080
- tomcat 8 on  port 9090

I can access to a webapp in  tomcat 8 by url `http://adresseip:9090` ( confifuration in tomcat 8 server.xml)

I want to acces the same webapp (in tomcat8)  throught tomcat7 `http://adresseip:8080/MyApp`

How can i redirect a url from tomcat7 to tomcat8? 
Should i do configuration in apache httpd.conf? 
If yes, how ? 
Thank you.